# Understanding Core Videos CVPixelBufferPool and CVOpenGLESTextureCache semantics

Tags: ios, caching, opengl-es, textures, core-video

I'm refactoring my iOS OpenGL-based rendering pipeline. My pipeline consist of many rendering steps, hence I need a lot of intermediate textures to render to and read from. Those textures are of various types (unsigned byte and half float) and may posses a different number of channels.

To save memory and allocation effort I recycled textures that were used by previous steps in the pipeline and are no longer needed. In my previous implementation I did that on my own.

In my new implementation I want to use the APIs provided by the Core Video framework for that; especially since they provide much faster access to the texture memory from the CPU. I understand that the [`CVOpenGLESTextureCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreVideo/Reference/CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush) allows me to create OpenGL textures out of [`CVPixelBuffer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVPixelBufferRef/)s that can be created directly or using a [`CVPixelBufferPool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVPixelBufferPoolRef/). However, I am unable to find any documentation describing how they really work and how they play together.

Here are the things I want to know:

- For getting a texture from the `CVOpenGLESTextureCache` I always need to provide a pixel buffer. Why is it called "cache" if I need to provide the memory anyways and are not able to retrieve an old, unused texture?
- The `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush` function "flushes currently unused resources". How does the cache know if a resource is "unused"? Are textures returned to the cache when I release the corresponding `CVOpenGLESTextureRef`? The same question applies to the `CVPixelBufferPool`.
- Am I able to maintain textures with different properties (type, # channels, ...) in one texture cache? Does it know if a textures can be re-used or needs to be created depending on my request?
- `CVPixelBufferPool`s seem only to be able to manage buffers of the same size and type. This means I need to create one dedicated pool for each texture configuration I'm using, correct?

I'd be really happy if at least some of those questions could be clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, well you will not actually be able to find anything. I looked and looked and the short answer is you just need to test things out to see how the implementation functions. You can find my blog post on the subject along with example code at [opengl_write_texture_cache](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post12_opengl_write_texture_cache). Basically, it seems that the way it works is that the texture cache object "holds" on to the association between the buffer (in the pool) and the OpenGL texture that is bound when a triangle render is executed. The result is that the same buffer should not be returned by the pool until after OpenGL is done with it. In the weird case of some kind of race condition, the pool might get 1 buffer larger to account for a buffer that is held too long. What is really nice about the texture cache API is that one only needs to write to the data buffer once, as opposed to calling an API like glTexImage2D() which would "upload" the data to the graphics card.